# workflow 4 activity designer IValueConverter

Tags: c#, .net, workflow-foundation-4, ivalueconverter

Lets say i have an activity with InArgument<int> ProductId

I'd like to expose in the activity designer a combobox to show all Products and the user can select a product.

I can show the list of product in the combo no problem. But how do I **bind** the selected product to the InArgument<int> of my custom activity?

I suppose I need some kind of ValueConverter? Not sure how to code the value converter for this case, if anybody has an idea, suggestion, will be helpful. I have to convert the InArgument<int> to an int? and the convert back from int to InArgument<int>

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

```
public class ArgumentToInt32Converter: IValueConverter {
    object IValueConverter.Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) {
        object convertedValue = null;
        if (value != null) {
            ModelItem argumentModelItem = value as ModelItem;
            if (argumentModelItem != null && argumentModelItem.Properties["Expression"] != null && argumentModelItem.Properties["Expression"].Value != null) {
                if (argumentModelItem.Properties["Expression"].ComputedValue.GetType() == typeof(Literal <Int32> )) {
                    convertedValue = (argumentModelItem.Properties["Expression"].ComputedValue as Literal <Int32> ).Value;
                } else {
                    convertedValue = null
                }
            }
        }
        return convertedValue;
    }

    object IValueConverter.ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) {
        // Convert Int32 value to InArgument<Int32>
        Int32 itemContent = (Int32) value;
        VisualBasicValue <Int32> vbArgument = new VisualBasicValue <Int32> (itemContent);
        InArgument <Int32> inArgument = new InArgument <Int32> (vbArgument);
        return inArgument;
    }
}
```

*Modified from [this answer](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wfprerelease/thread/82ddccf2-c587-46fc-8a7d-5170e07ca2c4/)*

Answer (score 1):

This is my attempt at making a more generic solution to this.  I have several properties - some IEnumerable, some string, some int, and to make a value converter for each seems like the wrong approach.  I'd be interested to know what cases I haven't caught here because I am relatively new to WF.  Hopefully this helps someone.

```
public class ArgumentConverter : IValueConverter
{
    #region IValueConverter Members

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        object convertedValue = null;
        if(value != null)
        {
            var argumentModelItem = value as ModelItem;

            if(argumentModelItem != null)
            {
                ModelProperty argumentModelProperty = argumentModelItem.Properties["Expression"];

                if(argumentModelProperty != null && argumentModelProperty.Value != null)
                {
                    var computedValue = argumentModelProperty.ComputedValue;

                    var activity = (Activity) computedValue;
                    convertedValue = WorkflowInvoker.Invoke(activity)["Result"];
                }
            }
        }
        return convertedValue;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        // here targetType should be InArgument<T>
        // assume a single generic argument
        Type arg0 = targetType.GetGenericArguments()[0];

        ConstructorInfo argConstructor = targetType.GetConstructor(new[] {arg0});

        var argument = argConstructor.Invoke(new[] { value });

        return argument;
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Comment: **NOTE**: I have discovered that the above code will only execute once due to the way `ComputedValue` and workflow instances work. It does work however if you serialize the activity, de-serialize it, and pass the fresh deserialized instance into `WorkflowInvoker.Invoke()`.